# Process exited prematurely with a SIGSEGV signal

Tags: c++, string, char

This code shows this SIGSEGV error, which I understand, is a segmentation error. Can someone please help!
The code **returns the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string.**
I am using this on a programming challenge so this is only a function.

So, If I input "aabcdef" it should return 2 because 'a' occurs twice. Input can contain alphabets as well as numerics.

```
int duplicateCount(const char* in)
{
int a[39]={0},b=0;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(in);i++)
{
    if(in == NULL)
        return 0;


    if((int)in[i] < 97)
    {
        a[(int)in[i]]++;
    }
    a[tolower(in[i])-'a'+1]++;
}

for(int i=0;i<39;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>1)

        b++;
}


return b;

}
```

Comment: what about `a['Z']++;` outta bound?

Comment: @snr 'Z' will be converted to 'z', thus a[26]++; not outta bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

```
if((int)in[i] < 97)
{
    a[(int)in[i]]++;
}
a[tolower(in[i])-'a'+1]++;
```

you may write outside of bounds which, as we know, has UB.

---

**Fix**

First you have to check if character is letter with `isalpha(c)`

Then you have to transform character to lower via `tolower(c)`

And sub the first low case letter in alphabet `c - 'a'`

Then you can index an array and increment its value.

**[Here is fixed code](https://ideone.com/jUXCY9)**

---

Since we are in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you may use `std::map`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string text("aabbc");
    std::map<char, int> letterCounter;

    for(auto& it : text)
    {
        letterCounter[it]++;
    }

    for (auto& it : letterCounter)
    {
        if (it.second > 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Character " << it.first << " has appeared "
                      << it.second << " times." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Character a has appeared 2 times.
Character b has appeared 2 times.
```